# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Even without seeing your JSON string i can tell from the error message that it is not the correct structure to be parsed into an instance of your class.

Gson is expecting your JSON string to begin with an object opening brace. e.g.

```
{
```

But the string you have passed to it starts with an open quotes

```
"
```

Comment: post the json string.

Comment: i have posted my codings here,please check it 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761344/java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-string-at-line-1-c

Comment: is anything i want to add in my codings ??